# Convert input box to combobox for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code is functioning correctly.  However, I need help getting the "input" tag to display like a combobox. I have tried to styled the inputbox as a combobox without success. I am also looking for a way to make the code work with a combobox by building the options dynamically.  Any and all help is appreciated.

```js
$(function () {
  var availableTags = new Array(1000000);
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < availableTags.length; i++) {
    availableTags[j++] = i.toString();
  }
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (req, responseFn) {

      var re = req.term;
      var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
      var a = $.grep(availableTags, function (item) {
        return matcher.test(item);
      });
      responseFn(a.slice(0, 5));
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      if (ui.item && ui.item.value) {
        var titleinput = ui.item.value;
        ui.item.value = $.trim(titleinput);
        alert(ui.item.value);
      }
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      if (!valid) {
        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
        $(this).val("");
        select.val("");
        return false;
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.custom-combobox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 0;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;  
}

/*
.custom-combobox-list-item {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-combobox-input , .custom-combobox-list-item.ui-state-focus {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
*/

#tags {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" type="text" class="custom-combobox" value="">
```

Comment: can u plz add jsfiddle

Comment: @JotDhaliwal: You can add runnable code snippets inside Stack Overflow now: [StackExchange Blog: Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: I converted the static code into a runnable snippet. :-p

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: Using the correct version of jQuery and jQueryUI works. Make sure they are compatible.

Comment: @bronothevibrator i just had a thought, i posted a way to do this below but then realised that if the list of options was 1million long it would be quicker to type it rather than scroll down a page a rediculous amount to find the correct option to select? so what is the realistic amount of options you expect to have in the `text/combobox`?

Comment: I expect to have 1 million numbers but only five listed as the autocomplete find matches.  Please see the code I posted.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator If you have million rows of data, you shouldn't manage it in pure JS. Store it at server side in a database and make ajax-requests to the server when the user is typing and search there. Then send only the results back to the client. You can do it with select2, check out the "Loading Remote Data" section on the select2's page.

Comment: The data is to determine which page of a grid view to display.  The data could grow to 1 million page numbers.  I only need to work with the numbers as the data.  The current legacy code works fine but the current combo box is not able to hold the large number of numbers and it does not employ the auto complete functionality.  The data is actually all numbers that could grow to 1 million.  If you look at the code I posted the 1 million numbers work fine and is exactly what I am looking for.  I just need the box to look like a combo box.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: I understand what you want, but I don't think it's a good idea at all. If there was a grid with more than a million pages, I think you should provide an easier way of paging. As a user I don't want to have a combobox to hold only numbers (which takes a lot of resources to render, think about old computers and mobile devices too). It's a lot more easier to input a page number then hit enter and the script should load that page. I don't see any point in the combobox solution.

Comment: This is the current requirements.  I don't make the rules.  Remember this is a legacy application and the users want to keep their combo box.  I guess people are just resistant to change ...

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator ok, but try to show a user a combobox (a simple select tag would be good) with more than 10.000 items in it, and tell the user try it out. I don't think he/she will find it useful. And if you would have an autocomplete or a filter, then what's the point in the combobox? If I start to enter "10" then what should happen? The autocomplete can't complete it, since the "10" is exactly in the list. If you created a filter, I got "10", "101","102".. and so on (about 10.000 items) in the list. Then why I don't want to simply enter "10124" to go to that page?

Comment: @Fenistil: I believe the posted solution is what the user wants.  if I can't get a CSS or JavaScript solution to this problem I am thinking about putting an image next to the textbox just to make it look like a combobox.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: But then my suggested select2 + ajax solution could work well for you. Why don't you try that one?

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator why can't you use the example on this page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @Fenistil: Could you please demonstrate how to use your select2 with ajax to solve this problem?

Comment: Salman A: I need to dynamically populate the list plus the solution needs to use ajax and the autocomplete must only match left to right.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: I've modified my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `datalist` to transfer the options to the `text input` which will then turn it into a `combobox`

I slimmed your code write down to the very basics to make a simple example.

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" name="tags" type="text" list="options" class="custom-combobox" value="">

<datalist id="options">
    <!-- it puts the options here then the input type text gets them as select options -->
</datalist> 

$(function () {
  var availableTags = new Array(10);
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < availableTags.length; i++) {
    $('#options').append("<option value='" + i + "'>");
  }

});
```

here is a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/6onsk5kp/)** showing the basic functionality

Comment: This code did not work for me  JSFIDDLE. Additionally it will not satisfy the requirements:

Comment: This code did not work for me  in JSFIDDLE. Additionally it will not satisfy the requirements: 1. It should do autocomplete with the display showing five items at a time.  2. The autocomplete should display the items with matching characters from the left.  The array should be able to hold at least 1,000,000 numbers and be very responsive (per my example).

Comment: +100 for this answer! NO Jquery UI required... You're an evil genious!!

Answer (score 2):

After a research I found [Combo-Box-jQuery-Plugin](https://github.com/dellsala/Combo-Box-jQuery-Plugin) written by [dellsala](https://github.com/dellsala).

**What is it ?**

Turns a `<input type="text">` into a combo box.

- autocomplete
- keyboard controls
- most styles can be customized via css
- list of values can be changed dynamically

**How it looks like ?**

[image]

**Why I suggest that ?**

This is not intended for extending `<select>` elements. Many other jquery "combo box" plugins out there behave more like searchable select elements with disctinct labels and values for each option. **This plugin simply allows the user** to choose from existing text values or supply their own.

**How to use ?**  http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/eh0gse2f/

```
<div class="inputCombox">
    <label for="input1">Field1:</label>
    <input id="input1" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="inputCombox">
    <label for="input2">Field2:</label>
    <input id="input2" type="text" value="" />
</div>

jQuery(function () {
    var varValue = 12;
    var aval = [
        'Yo',
        '1',
        'Jo',
    varValue.toString()];

    //#Example 1 
    jQuery('#input1').combobox(aval);

    //#Example 2 
    jQuery('#input2').combobox([
        'Yo',
        '1',
        'Jo']);     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Check this it might be helpful

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox

Comment: jquery ui works for my sharepoint solution too . check my answer which is modified verion of the jqueryui.com page http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/129776/16880

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

It's pretty simple, just look that is an input, with an anchor at the end.

Just click on "view source" to see how it's implemented.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the bootstrap tags

```
$("#tags").tagsinput("Amsterdam,Washington,Los Angeles");
```

[Bootstrap Tags Input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Comment: The list needs to be built dynamically not prepopulated.

Comment: Where do you get the list?

Comment: The javascript is generating the list.  I suggest you run the code and see how it works.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: If creating a typeahead drop-down list of the numbers 0-999,999 is what you are aiming for, the code already does that... `Underscore.js`'s [`range()`](http://underscorejs.org/#range) function is a port of python's.  To build your array, you could just call `_.range(1000000)` :-)

Comment: Yes, the code currently builds the list.  However, it is using an input tag that looks like an input box.  I am trying to get it to look like a combo box.  The problem I have is that I am unable to style it to look like a combo box and I an unable to get it to work when I change the input tag to a select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

To populate the Select2 with an ajax call, try this:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $result = array();

    //Do something with the search string ($searchfor), eg. find the desired results
    $result[] = array('id' => '1', 'text' => '101');
    $result[] = array('id' => '2', 'text' => '102');
    $result[] = array('id' => '3', 'text' => '103');
    $result[] = array('id' => '4', 'text' => '104');
    $result[] = array('id' => '5', 'text' => '105');

    //Send the ajax results formatted as JSON
    print(json_encode($result));    
?>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" value="" style="width: 300px;">
<script>
$('#tags').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://yourdomain.com/ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                searchfor: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot use pre-created data to populate it.  Like in the example, the data has to be generated on the fly.  The current example with the 1,000,000 numbers is what I am looking for.  The solution with Json will not work for me.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator: Modified according to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick workaround to make your inout look like a select. No code changes needed, just some HTML/CSS. I made your input transparent, and layered a select behind it. The functionality is still handled by your input, but now it looks exactly like the select.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/xy0mxst4/1/

Trick - Do this with the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <select id="fake-tags"></select>
  <input id="tags" type="text" class="custom-combobox" value="" />
</div>
```

and add this CSS to make the input appear above the select to handle the functionality:

```
#tags {
  width: 40px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
#tags:focus {
  outline: 0
}
#fake-tags {
  width: 50px;
}
```

It's a hack, but it's a super-simple one and it sounds like it might be just what you need - you already have working code, you just need it to look a bit different.

This is inspired by the 'good old day's, when people used to layer a nice looking but fake file upload control on top of the nasty default browser one. The default did the real work, and the fake one just provided the nice UI. People don't do this so much now that we have the FileAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I will place the image of a clickable down arrow next to the textbox.  I will display 1 to 10 in the list box if the user clicks the image instead of entering data into the text box.